# How these two steps in Fourier transform are equal?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

**Step1:**
(limit $Δs$ tends to $0$) (Summation $n=1$ to $\infty$)  $\cos(nΔs(t-x)) Δs$

**Step2**
(Integration from $0$ to $\infty$) $\cos(s(t-x)) ds$

How is Step1 equal to Step2?

Comment: It's not much different from the usual Riemann integral on a uniform partition, except that the domain of integration is infinite so there are some technicalities.

Comment: As it stands the question does not make sense because neither the integral nor the sum exists.

Comment: Could you please type with [$\LaTeX$-$\texttt{MathJax}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) ?.

Comment: I found this in Fourier transform doing rigorously the Lemmas

Comment: Mr. Ian sir, how does nΔs bocome s?